# php mysql match against no results

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

Alright, so I'm trying to do a Full Text search on my mysql table. Here is the query

```
SELECT *,
       MATCH (title, joke) AGAINST ('welcome') AS relevance,
       MATCH (title) AGAINST ('welcome') AS title_relevance
FROM jokes
WHERE MATCH (title, joke) AGAINST ('welcome') 
AND flags < 5
ORDER BY title_relevance + relevance + ups DESC, downs ASC LIMIT 0, 30
```

and here is my table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jokes` (
  `jid` varchar(24) NOT NULL,
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `joke` longtext NOT NULL,
  `ups` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `downs` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `flags` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `createddate` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `editdate` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`jid`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `searcher` (`title`,`joke`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `title` (`title`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I have a couple rows that contain either welcome in the title, or in the joke, but I don't seem to get any results. It doesn't matter what word I search for.

I've also tried removing AND `flags < 5` and also `ups DESC, downs ASC LIMIT 0,30`

Both don't seem to work.

This is what I do with the php code

```
if($st->prepare($SearchQuery))
{
    if(!$st->execute())
        ChromePhp::log("Execute Error: " . $st->error);
    else
    {
        $results = fetchAll($st);
        $ret = new stdClass();
        $ret->TotalCount = 0;
        $ret->Results = $results;
        return $ret;
    }
}
```

and this is fetchAll(which has worked for every other query I've tossed at it).

```
function fetchAll($result)
    {    
        $array = array();

        if($result instanceof mysqli_stmt)
        {
            $result->store_result();

            $variables = array();
            $data = array();
            $meta = $result->result_metadata();

            while($field = $meta->fetch_field())
                $variables[] = &$data[$field->name]; // pass by reference

            call_user_func_array(array($result, 'bind_result'), $variables);

            $i=0;
            while($result->fetch())
            {
                $array[$i] = array();
                foreach($data as $k=>$v)
                    $array[$i][$k] = $v;
                $i++;

                // don't know why, but when I tried $array[] = $data, I got the same one result in all rows
            }
        }
        elseif($result instanceof mysqli_result)
        {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
                $array[] = $row;
        }

        return $array;
    }
```

Anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: Removing order clauses is (almost never) going to affect the lack/presence of results. How much data do you have in the database? remember that fulltext will consider any word(s) that appear in 50%+ of the fields as noise and ignore them.

Comment: What happens when you just run the query directly on your DB (sans you're querying code)?

Comment: When i run the SQL directly to my database(via SQL in mysqladmin) I get no results eather. I only have I'd say 7 entries in the database.

Comment: So no ideas as to what's wrong?

Comment: @MarcB How do you fix that 50% number, or remove it all together?

Comment: @MarcB Or a better question I guess would be how would I switch my query to a boolean mode, so it ignore the threshold?

Comment: Even IN BOOLEAN MODE doesn't seem to work. Tried searching for 'welcome' and it wouldn't return any results, even though i have 2 rows that have welcome. But some words seem to work. I've read through the docs and it's supposed to ignore the 50% rule, so I don't see why it's not working.

Comment: I don't know, I can't get this FullText search to work decently, so I'm just going to go back to using LIKE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because **'welcome'** is a **STOPWORD**, so that MySQL skips to search for this word.

See the stopword list of MySQL Full text search here

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-stopwords.html

And please remind the length of words in the search phrase also, if its length less than 4, by default MySQL will skips for search it too.

For example "the way I am", "usa", "php", "job" etc (read more about `ft_min_word_len`)

Comment: So, to clarify, 'welcome' is a stopword, which means a Fulltext search will ignore it

Comment: I asked you a question, why you no answer?

Comment: @kelton52 where is your question?

Comment: @kelton52 can you give me your scripts contains db schema and data?

Comment: "So, to clarify, 'welcome' is a stopword, which means a Fulltext search will ignore it? "

Comment: I did, but it seemed kind of vague.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not too sure if it will make much of a difference, but have you tried using Boolean Mode? Like this:

```
AGAINST ('welcome' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Comment: I have but it didn't seem to do what I wanted it to. MySql just doesn't seem up to par for search engine work